# What am I? - An object riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am named after something organic,
>
> And yet I am not alive.
>
> I'm always being controlled,
>
> And yet I hold all of the power.
>
> My only job is to create,
>
> and yet my only job is to destroy.
>
> I am used to help the world,
>
> And yet I need to hurt it.
>
> What am I?

*Explain every line of the riddle in your answer in order for it to be counted correct.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a

> Power Plant

---

I am named after something organic,

> A "plant", as in a shrub or tree

And yet I am not alive.

> The machinery in a power plant is not considered alive except maybe in a philosophical sense.

I'm always being controlled,

> You need to control a power plant to keep it functioning efficiently

And yet I hold all of the power.

> Provides power to the community

My only job is to create,

> Generates electricity

and yet my only job is to destroy.

> Burns fuel to do so

I am used to help the world,

> Electricity is the foundation of modern technology

And yet I need to hurt it.

> But burning fuel hurts the environment

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are:

> the sun

I am named after something organic

> According to Google the word "sun" comes from "son", as in a male child.  "Old English sunne, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch zon and German Sonne, from an Indo-European root shared by Greek hēlios and Latin sol"

And yet I am not alive.

> The sun is not alive.

I'm always being controlled,

> We're controlling it by using it for heat, light, and the generation of electricity.

And yet I hold all of the power.

> The sun is the original source of energy for the earth.  Even fossil fuels were originally living things that were powered by the sun.

My only job is to create,

> Creates light and life on earth.  Alternatively, creates new elements inside itself through fusion.

and yet my only job is to destroy.

> Burns constantly (both fission and fusion) until it will eventually burn out.  Sunlight (UV radiation) is also extremely destructive.

I am used to help the world,

> We can't live without it.

And yet I need to hurt it.

> This one is tough, but I think the fact that sunlight is extremely damaging satisfies this clue.  The sun doesn't have a physical need to cause damage, but one of the clues says that it's not alive, and no non-living thing has needs like a living thing would.

Answer (score 0):

I am named after something organic,

> You are CARBON.

And yet I am not alive.

> CARBON is not alive

I'm always being controlled,

> CARBON in compounds is controlled by bonds.

And yet I hold all of the power.

> CARBON is the basis of all organic molecules.

My only job is to create,

> CARBON creates life.

and yet my only job is to destroy.

> Many CARBON compounds burn or pollute.

I am used to help the world,

> CARBON certainly helps the world, eg. as food and fuel.

And yet I need to hurt it.

> CARBON creates pollution, which hurts people and the world.

What am I?

> CARBON

Comment: Hello @Vassilis Parassidis. I suggest you put your answers and explanations in Spoilers. Thanks.

Comment: @DrD I've tried ›! before my answers and nothing gets hidden. If you can tell me how to use spoilers, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I did it and it seems to work. Not sure why it did not work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it will work for me next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that also appears to fit

> VACCINE

Because: Origin

> The origin of the word Vaccine is Latin word for Cow and related to Cowpox Virus which is Organic molecules.

Not alive

> Most vaccines are dead viruses

Controlled

> Vaccines are well regulated and distribution controlled

I hold all the power

> Vaccines hold power to stop the disease

My job is to create

> Create antibodies

My job is to destroy

> Destroy disease viruses

I am used to help the world: Obviously!

Yet I need to hurt it

> That darn needle hurts man!